# Are these breakers single-pole or double-pole?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I'm installing a Sense energy monitor and it needs a 2-pole, 240V breaker. I know I can piggyback off an existing 2-pole breaker, but am I correct that all of these are single-pole?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't recommend splicing or piggybacking when you have so many empty spaces. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojFIp.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Those 3 breakers are two-pole breakers.

I see piggybacking off an existing breaker is indicated as permitted in the installation instructions, installation instructions are part of the *NRTL Listing*. You probably wouldn't have a function problem but you could run afoul of the Code if the installation instructions for the other item requires a dedicated circuit.

Landing a second wire under the breaker termination is also subject to the *Listing* of the breaker, most breakers also have the restrictions on the breaker. Schneider Square D QO breakers "have pressure plate terminals suitable for single or two-wire terminations"  There is a chart that shows minimum size is #14. https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Catalog&p_File_Name=0730CT9801.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=0730CT9801 .

Comment: _pours a cup of coffee. Hands it to NSP..._ :)

Comment: Sorry, just woke up, will correct. The doc is the correct document, just crossed up wrong  brand name in my text.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, those are 2 pole breakers. You are not allowed to piggyback off any breakers in the panel. Any connections to existing circuits must be made outside the panel.

Comment: Splices are not prohibited. NEC Article 312.8 Switch and overcurrent device enclosures (A) Splices, Taps and Feed-Through Conductors. ...shall be permitted (1)The total of all conductors...does not exceed 40% of the cross sectional area of that space...

Comment: Square D QO breakers allow for 1 or 2 wire connections to the breaker , a splice in the panel is also legal, I routinely splice multiple conductors when doing panel upgrades because modern panels are larger so adding wire is regularly required, I have never had a inspector even check my fill, using the panel or a gutter,

Comment: First: splices in panels are *explicitly* permitted by 312.8(A) provided you don't overflow the gutter (which from all accounts I have hard is quite a feat to pull off).  Second: Square-D breakers in the 15, 20, and 30A sizes (both QO and HOM, but not GFCI, AFCI, or HOMT) are all listed for terminating 1-2 14-10AWG wires

Comment: Those are both common and understandable misconceptions, that "wire-nut splices are not allowed in panels" and that "you can't double-tap breakers".  That's because in some cases they are true, but not *El NEC* territory and QO breakers.